# Jupyter Notebook memory usage tops out until there's an error

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run some iteration which populates a large list until my memory usage reaches 60%, use that list, delete that list, then run it all again. Something like this:

```
while True:
    ls = []
    usage = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
    print(usage)
    if usage  < 60:
         ls.append(bigThing)
    else:
         break
    use_list(ls)

    #seems redundant, but did this just in case
    del ls
```

Regardless of what I did, It seemed like the memory usage converged to around 60. The first time I run the cell it might look like this:

```
30
35
40
50
62
```

the next few times I run the cell it would look like this, where it seems like there's a slight reduction that stays static until a threshold is reached

```
58.7
58.7
58.7
58.7
58.7
60
```

then it would just go straight to `60.1`, for instance, and never iterate.

If I ran any code with an error, for instance deleting `ls` twice in a row, it seemed to reset the memory usage, it would drop back down to 30, and I could iterate again. However, if I did this in a `try` block,  it would remain the same. This makes me think there's some moving cap that resets when there's an error, but that's why I'm here: how the heck do I keep it from "capping out" like this?

Comment: (the question was why `del` was where it was) The point of this is to try to delete ls before another iteration, so that the value of `usage` will be lower on the next iteration, but as mentioned in the question, it stays (I think superficially) high

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python), the python garbage collector won't automatically free up unreferenced memory immediately. It might depend on your use case, but for me, using `import gc` and `gc.collect()` in certain points, to manually command the garbage collector to clean up the data, worked well. So my current program looks kind of like this:

```
while True:
   ls = make_list_to_mem_thresh()
   use_list(ls)
   del ls
   gc.collect()
```

It's likely that, when a cell fails, it triggers the garbage collector. If that is the case, that would explain the "capping" phenomenon described in the question.